Why is the Gradle build failing?
My build failed after following with the following message 

Task :extensions:superuser-seed:compileJava FAILED /home/joba/MinimumViableDataspace/extensions/superuser-seed/src/main/java/org/eclipse/edc/identityhub/seed/ParticipantContextSeedExtension.java:94:
error: cannot find symbol
.orElse(generatedKey.get("apiKey").toString());
^   symbol:   method get(String)   location: variable generatedKey of type
CreateParticipantContextResponse 1 error
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

The command I triggered was:

./gradlew clean build --warning-mode all

I am running Ubuntu Linux in Windows with WSL-2. Thanks for your hints to tackle that issue. I am wondering if there is a problem regarding the Gradle-versions mentioned in the Open Source Project EDC MVD: https://github.com/eclipse-edc/MinimumViableDataspace

I updated the project to the latest version - now the build works.
